# The Chat subdomain is missing the #LoveOverflows logo

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I know it's temporary, but it is part of the site, so I imagine the Chat domain should have the logo for the duration of this event. Currently it's still the default:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Chat is a separate codebase and (by now) there's no point in changing the logo there since we'll be reverting back to the regular orange in the next day or so.

Comment: Maybe a good thing to make a note of in the future, then.