# When are we going to get the old logo back?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, logo

I perfectly understand why SO has the LGBT-rainbow logo right now, and I respect the admins' decision to make it that way. But, seriously, it's been up for, what, three days?

I am really sorry if I offended anyone, if I did, I didn't mean to! But I have my reasons for asking this.

You see, I can't help being nervous. I live in Russia, and here, the backlash against such stuff is tremendous, and happens on the political level, because we have a "law against homosexual propaganda" in place.

For example, there were even more calls from people in the gov't to block Facebook for good lately, because of their rainbow-coloured profile pics.

I know that chances this backlash will catch SO and harm its availability in Russia in any way are quite low, but I'm still nervous.

So please, can anyone tell me if we will be getting the old logo back soon?

Comment: They had to create vote to ask users if they want to see gay flag as logo.

Comment: How to block images in IE: Tools > Options > Advanced > Multimedia > Uncheck "Show Images"

Comment: How to block images in FF: In the address bar > about:config > permissions.default.image > change value to 1 (which is never load the images)

Comment: How to block images in Chrome: In the address bar > chrome://settings/ > Show Advanced Settings > Privacy > Images > Do Not Show Any Images

Comment: How to block images in Safari: Preferences > Appearance > Uncheck "Display Images When The Page Opens"

Comment: How to block images in Opera: Right click page > Content block toolbar > Click the images or plug-in content that you would like Opera to block

Comment: The above is if you were also worried about someone seeing the logo while you were using the site. I realize it doesn't help with your general worry about your government being upset by it.

Comment: Related: you can browse SO and MSO (and most but not all SE sites) via SSL. I use NoScript to enforce it permanently. Bear in mind that this does not in itself hide you're visiting SO, however.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As I said [in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298087/when-are-we-going-to-get-the-old-logo-back/298088?noredirect=1#comment214016_298088), we aim to revert back to the normal logo at around 2:00 PM Eastern (18:00 UTC).

As it would be part of a build, please don't get upset if it doesn't happen exactly at that time, as technical considerations might delay things.

However, all going AccordingToPlan ™, it should be back to normal at around the same time we changed it on Friday.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-planned]?

Answer (score -1):

I personally like the new logo, but to answer your question, according to [The Chat subdomain is missing the #LoveOverflows logo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298082/404623):

> We'll be reverting back to the regular orange in the next day or so.

Comment: I would appreciate a more specific answer to this from a Stack Exchange Valued Associate.

Comment: @AdamDavis [Anna Lear](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297921/the-chat-subdomain-is-missing-the-loveoverflows-logo/298082#298082), whom this answer is quoting, is a developer at Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I am well aware of that.  And so far no one has said, "The change will occur at xx:xx GMT" - I've seen very rough estimates ranging from weekend, to "few days" to "next day or so" and this could mean today, or tomorrow, or, at a stretch the next day. I'm simply expressing a desire for more specific information from at least as trusted a source as this general information.

Comment: @AdamDavis Is it really going to change your daily life that much? I think knowing that the change isn't permanent and that we'll be back to normal in short order seems sufficient to me. Needing to set an alarm clock to the precise moment it changes seems dramatic.

Comment: @AdamDavis It's hard to pinpoint an exact time because it has to go out as part of a build, and it's impossible to predict when everything else that has to go out with it will be 'baked enough'. I'm going to _guess_ at before the end of the work day in NYC, and I'll ask around on the core end for someone to post a more narrow estimate (provided one can be determined).

Comment: @AdamDavis _Near_ 2:00 PM Eastern, around the same time that it went out on Friday. Again, though, it's hard to time these things precisely, if it turns out to be 4 or 5, there are probably very good technical (or, explosion avoidance) reasons for it.