# Are political profiles that could possibly affect the participations of other users allowed?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

- Related but not exactly the same: [Are political avatars and profiles
  OK?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok)
- Related discussion on similar event: [When are we going to get the
  old logo back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298087/when-are-we-going-to-get-the-old-logo-back)
- the Related event: [Can Stack Overflow and Meta's logos be changed
  temporarily to the “#LoveOverflows” logo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow)

---

Are political profiles that could possibly affect the participation of other users allowed in SO?

I came across a [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%E5%85%AD%E5%9B%9B%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6-%E6%B3%95%E8%BD%AE%E5%8A%9F-%E7%BA%B3%E7%B1%B3%E6%AF%94%E4%BA%9A-%E5%A8%81%E8%A7%86), expressing the profile owner's opinions on Religions, Chinese government's affairs. Different from expressing his opinions, this user wrote:

> Why I'm doing this: in March 2015, my girlfriend's mother was kept 15 days in prison without trial or accusation

> My goals: make the Great Firewall of China GFW block Stack Overflow pages where I have posted, in order to make Chinese programmers:

> - mad and demand direct elections, freedom of speech and human rights
> - talk to me, so I can gather pro-freedom contacts and better understand China: Twitter or Github.
> - Public contact preferred, even if anonymous.

I am not sure if this kind of profile is appropriate to this community, hence the question.

I am neutral to political opinions, free will.

I am, however, against this kind of profiles because:

1. It's not related to programming. It's more like taking advantage of the question answered and the publicity of S/O to send out one's personal messages.
2. It might violate the community's model: [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

> Bigotry of any kind. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)

3. It might violate the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) (under the **Subscriber Content** section).

> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party, (b) reveals any trade secret, unless Subscriber owns the trade secret or has the owner’s permission to post it, (c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another, (d) is libelous, defamatory, abusive, threatening, harassing, hateful, offensive or otherwise violates any law or right of any third party, (e) contains a virus, trojan horse, worm, time bomb or other computer programming routine or engine that is intended to damage, detrimentally interfere with, surreptitiously intercept or expropriate any system, data or information, or (f) remains posted after Subscriber has been notified that such Subscriber Content violates any of sections (a) to (e) of this sentence.

4. For the party that are offended, it might affect the participation of offended parties and as consequences, the quality of contents, the diversity of participators for this community.

Taking this profile as an example, I wasn't offended of any kind but I do think words like "共匪" or "共惨党" might be offensive to communists.

The goals of the profile, as stated, are to made the Chinese government to censor S/O and possibly block the IOs to S/O and to make unrelated Chinese professions mad. Which is possibly the worst idea I have ever heard over time.

I don't want to turn this question into a discussion on such profile but rather taking that profile as an example for seeking answers for a more general question.

Comment: All of that pales in comparison to this: "A funny effect of this is that if people @ mention you, then they also end up saying the taboo words." He's basically trying to make the rest of the community his unwitting pawns in order to give the (probably false) impression that the community at large holds the same sentiments that he does in order to get the site blocked. That makes him no better than the one he's crusading against, honestly.

Comment: "That makes him no better than the one he's crusading against, honestly." Putting naughty words in an online profile makes you as bad as a regime that imprisons people without trial? False equivalence much?

Comment: Oh look, another internet crusader. I think it's in SO's best interest to _"deal with this"_. The unlikely case of the GFW actually blocking those pages doesn't benefit SO in any way... Besides, it's not like a block on the pages that guy posted on, is going to make Chinese programmers _"mad and demand direct elections, freedom of speech and human rights"_... That's a pretty naive assumption -.-

Comment: @samgak I don't think it's a fair comparison. 1. I am not sure how to prove the authentication of his telling, but even sadly what he says is true, why not leave the judging job to the local authorities and courts? 2. Even if the story is sadly true, it still wouldn't make hijacking other people's question and references to send out his personal message right. You can't say 'oh because this bad so I can do this bad thing to unrelated parties in react.'

Comment: @samgak: Yes, false equivalence on your part. When did I ever compare those two directly? I know I edit my comments a lot but I'm pretty sure that wasn't the only sentence in my original comment.

Comment: From their profile: *Your government exploits and lies to you way more than democracies do*. How cute. And wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock That's the implied comparison you made. "the one he's crusading against" is the Chinese government. Makes no difference that you didn't state it directly.

Comment: @samgak: Your interpretation of "the one" is correct, but not "That". I never said "that" putting naughty words in your own profile was comparable to such atrocities. I said implicating unwilling parties by baiting them into giving the false impression that they supported the same political agenda was.

Comment: (Sure, it's pretty obvious to a reasonable person that they were just @'ing him by his name which happened to contain naughty words, but the point is that certain people choose not to see it that way.)

Comment: @BoltClock "implicating unwilling parties by baiting them into giving the false impression that they supported the same political agenda" hardly makes him "no better than" the Chinese government either, especially since as you acknowledge no reasonable person is going to see it that way.

Comment: @samgak: No better than the Chinese government according to them, anyway. Indeed that was where I wasn't entirely clear. My apologies for the commotion.

Comment: @BoltClock No problem, sorry if I was overly confrontational.

Comment: @samgak: Given the topic, it would be disconcerting if anyone *wasn't* being confrontational ;)

Comment: Seems easy enough to click away. It's not like it's porn or really NR gore... sure sure it offends some, but again - a *user* profile is well... their own user profile to *use* how they like. Within reason, of course. But when it comes to political stuff this is really tame. He's not really going extreme-o it's just some slight political posturing really.   BAsically, walk away if it bothers you; but it's not reasonable to censor this. Explain why you clicked on the user profile page? It was either curiosity... or curiosity. So that's what you got. Curiosity yields varying effects

Comment: @Coffee I clicked on it because of the sudden Chinese characters in one's name and they are really eye catching. I was not offended at all, just bothered -- a good question and a good answer with something personal blended in.  It's like taking a walk around a peaceful neighborhood and there are people jumps out telling me things which they personally believed in and really to express them out. I will walk away, but again, bothered, then, why allow this to happen? It's free to talk, but is it really the place to express such things?

Comment: Hmm. "Bandits" and "Total miserable party" (at least according to Google Translate - "Commie" & "Total bad party" according to Bing) don't seem to be *particularly* offensive, though I can see why the Chinese govt *might* be offended.

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer this question without focusing on the specifics here.

Comment: Do we really have to be nice to oppressive dictatorships?  Considering how many people communists have killed in the 20th century, I could not care less for their feelings.

Comment: @Suzker it *is* true. Why would I put my personal honesty at stake by telling such a blatant lie?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ping me on https://github.com/cirosantilli/chat/issues with examples of democracies that exploit people even more

Comment: @ChrisF the connotation of those Chinese terms is very light because they are so silly. The punch is on the messages.

Comment: @BoltClock and other admins: please ping people when their profiles are discussed :-)

Comment: @Ciro Santilli 六四事件 法轮功 纳米比亚 威视 

It _IS_ what you believed in, it is your _OPINION_, doesn't necessary make it true, it's true _ONLY_ to yourself.

With the discussions, the most important thing I learnt is that regardless of what you _believe_ in, users are free to express their _opinions_ on their personal profile, as long as it complies with the community rule. The discussions here is not trying to verify whether what you expressed is true or not.

Comment: @Suzker I only replied to "I am not sure how to prove the authentication of his telling", by "his telling", you do mean my GF's mother being in jail right? The "can I say it on the profile or not" is open to discussion on this thread and I haven't mentioned it in my comment.

Comment: @BoltClock "in order to give the (probably false) impression that the community at large holds the same sentiments that he does": this is just an observation of a side effect of all usernames. If you analyse individual comments it is clear that the person is just `@` mentioning someone else and does not necessarily share that opinion. That is like saying that when you `@` mention someone you like them, approving of their "personal mark". The main point is: even if you tell me to change my username, there will still be vestiges of it. That could be fixed by syncing mentions with profile names.

Comment: "Too young, too simple, sometimes naive...particularly this time."

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I don't think any action needs to be taken, or if it does then other profiles and avatars with political messages should be removed also.

To address the points:

> It's not related to programming. It's more like taking advantage of the question answered and the publicity of S/O to send out one's personal messages.

This is a general argument against all political messages in profiles and avatars, so if this one is a problem for this reason then other such political messages should be removed also.

> It might violate the community's model:
>
> > Bigotry of any kind. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)

Missing from that list is any mention of alienating or offending individuals or groups based on their political opinions. The last sentence leaves it open to doubt, but if politics is a category to be included in this list then it follows that other political messages should be removed too, lest they offend those that disagree with them.

> It might violate the Terms of Service (under the Subscriber Content section).

I'm not sure which clause you mean, but if you mean that it unfairly associates other posters with that message then isn't that true of other political profiles and avatars?

> For the party that are offended, it might affect the participation of offended parties and as consequences, the quality of contents, the diversity of participators for this community.

Again, same goes for other political messages and avatars.

The only thing that distinguishes this profile from other profiles with political messages (which are tolerated by SO) is the possibility - however remote - that it will provoke a reaction, in this case from the Chinese government. However if that is the real reason for taking it down then that makes a mockery of all this other talk about respecting people, being inclusive, not causing offence and so on, if those things are only deemed important enough to warrant action in the face of an implied threat.

For example, the profile in the question at the first link expresses support for the Palestinian cause, which may offend some people, yet it was deemed acceptable. Of course, the government of Israel is not going to block SO because of it. If that one is acceptable and this one isn't, what's the message there? We care about offending people, but only if they might retaliate in some way? If the desire not to cause offence was sincere, it would apply even in cases where the offended party isn't going to do anything about it.

There is one other case recently where a Russian SO member worried that the rainbow icon that was temporarily displayed in place of the usual SO icon would cause SO to be blocked in Russia because of laws against promoting a "gay agenda". If action wasn't taken in that case (which was more likely given that it was an "offical" endorsement and not just some random user's opinion), why take it in this one?

Comment: +1. Well thought out, and that last paragraph is a good example.

Comment: To be honest, I'd like to disagree. We can rationalize all you want, but I believe that user's profile is completely out of place in that it's deliberately annoying, invasive and spammy: it aggressively forces user's unsolicited opinion down my throat when I just wanted programming answers. At the core, it's 1. *OT*, 2.* unsolicited*, 3. *unnecessary* and 4. *sticks out like a sore thumb*, thus qualifying as spam in my book. I just wonder why can't we just stick to programming and occasional Perl jokes?

Comment: @TobiaTesan, How is it out of place? **1)** I think the torture methods by China is out of place in humanity. ..

Comment: .. ¶ Stackoverflow itself is built on things that are built on democracy, open-source free information, free speech, and **free thinking**. If you're living inside the firewall and don't have proper access to google (and of course the two links I wrote above), I'm afraid to tell you the truth that you don't have access to free thinking. You can rationalize all you want, but to attack the very first level of the World Trade Center is to attack the entire tower.

Comment: I'll repeat myself: *I just wonder why can't we just stick to programming and occasional Perl jokes.*

Comment: @TobiaTesan, As explained above, [you can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_they_came_...) for the very reason that every entity has seeds and roots, and to attack the roots of something is to attack it itself.